# Vue.js add function to a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Vue.js and I would like to add a function to my component, Map.vue, so when I click the button it calls a function declared in the same file :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="google-map" :id="mapName">
    </div>
    <button >Do stuff</button>  
  </div>
</template>
```

I have only seen examples when the function is declared in the App.vue. How do you do that in my Map.vue file ?

Comment: Trigger an event in child click method using `$emit(eventName)` and listen to an event in parent using `$on(eventName)`.

Comment: [This video](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/12) about parent-child communication might help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Events**

Both `App.vue` and `Map.vue` are components so they work the same for calling functions (methods) "in the same file" ([single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)).

Trigger an [event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) by adding `v-on:click="yourFunctionHere()"` and then make sure to declare your function in the `methods` object of the script section:

*Map.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="google-map" :id="mapName">
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="doStuff()">Do stuff</button>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      doStuff () {
        alert('Did something!')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Custom Events**

Since it's a little unclear what confused you about the child component `Map.vue` (since you understand the parent `App.vue`), perhaps you are asking how to call a function in `App.vue` from a button in the child `Map.vue`?

If that's the case, then you need to use [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) for child to parent communication:

*Map.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="google-map" :id="mapName">
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="doStuff()">Do stuff</button>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      doStuff () {
        this.$emit('childStuff', 'some value from child')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

*App.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Map v-on:childStuff="value => { parentStuff(value) }"></Map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Map from './components/Map'

  export default {
    components: {
      Map
    },

    methods: {
      parentStuff (value) {
        alert(value)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! For me that was the first case, just calling a function from the same component. Works like a charm.